# Using GitHub's Release functionality with a client and server project single repo

Tags: python, git, github, release

I have a single github repository for a client and server project I'm working on. I'm maintaining versions separately for both project components and will release them at different times and intervals. Different server versions have backwards compatibility.

Both components are written in python.

I would like to use github's releases interface (and API) to release versions for both components separately, and not quite sure how this should work. I googled for common practices and searched github's help and couldn't find anything that addresses my question.

I would also like to use github's releases API as an update mechanism (by pulling for the list of releases and comparing that to a local version) for at least the client component.

Any help or direction will be appreciated!

My question is how should I create the releases themselves? should I name them differently based on component? should I use the version field by including the component in it? Any other way?

Comment: If you're maintaining the versions separately and they have different release lifecycles...why not just have two repositories?  Since GitHub's release mechanism is based on tags in your repository, it's not really possible to version things separately within the same repository.

Comment: @larsks The client and server are tight together, and since I'm working on both changes quite frequently are done to both components in the same PR. It was a decision I made some time ago when I started the project, based on a decent amount of online reading about the two options. It is not carved in stone but I grew to like it that way.

Comment: Given the way GitHub's release mechanism work, I really think your two options are either (a) split them into two repositories, or (b) don't try to version them seperately.  If they're that tightly linked, having the same version for each component seems sane.  But maybe someone will wander by with a different idea...